# Why WebIde shows error for alert and console.log?

Tags: sapui5, sap-web-ide

I am using WebIde of SAPUI5 development.

If I write a `console.log` or `alert` it shows error of unexpected Alert and so on inside of the editor.

While the code works and I prefer to not see these errors inside of the editor.

How can I customize WebIde to not show these kind of errors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While it is **discouraged** to use `console.log` and `alert` statements in your code because

> [...] such messages are considered to be for debugging purposes and therefore not suitable to ship to the client [...]

http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-console

and

> [...] JavaScripts’ alert, confirm, and prompt functions are widely considered to be obtrusive as UI elements and should be replaced by a more appropriate custom UI implementation [...]

http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-alert

you can have your Linter configured to bypass these checks (although I would *not* recommend to do so)

**But keep in mind these checks are not specific to SAPUI5 or Web IDE, rather for every Javascript project!**

Anyway, since Web IDE uses ESLint, to disable the check, add the following on top of the affected Javascript file:

`/*eslint-disable no-console, no-alert */`

Comment: Even better would be to use `jQuery.sap.log.debug(msg)`, then you don't have to fiddle with your ESLint file.